# Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow A$ be 2 surjective Functions. Show that $f\circ g = id \iff g\circ f = id$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've been sitting on this problem for a bit and trying to solve it using the definition of surjectivity and the definition of the composition, but I feel stuck.

According to surjectivity, for each $b \in B$ exists an $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$, and for each $a \in A$ exists a $b \in B$ with $f(b) = a$.

For $f\circ g$ we have: $f\circ g: B \rightarrow B$

For $g\circ f$ we have: $g\circ f: A \rightarrow A$

The definition of composition would tell us that: $g(b) \subseteq A$ and $f(a) \subseteq B$

So they seem to be their own inverse functions, but are they that truly? Can we say that g(b) produces a value that will take us back to b if we apply f to it?

Would it be simpler to just prove $f\circ g = g\circ f$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}$. Let $a\in A$; you want to prove that $g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=a$. Since $g$ is surjective, there is some $b\in B$ such that $a=g(b)$. But$$a=g(b)\implies f(a)=f\bigl(g(b)\bigr)=b$$and therefore$$g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=g(b)=a.$$

Comment: Oh, so id stands for identity. I thought it was just a value holder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a categorical approach. Let us first derive a nice cancelation property of surjective functions which is useful on its own.  Suppose that $f:A\to B$ is surjective, and $h_1,h_2:B\to C$ are arbitrary.  If $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ f$, then $h_1=h_2$.

We will prove the contrapositive, thet if $h_1\neq h_2$, then $h_1\circ f\neq h_2\circ f$. If $h_1\neq h_2$, that means we can find some $b\in B$ such that $h_1(b)\neq h_2(b)$.  Because $f$ is surjective, we can find some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.  Then $h_1\circ f(a)=h_1(b)\neq h_2(b)=h_2\circ f(a)$, so $h_1\circ f$ disagrees with $h_2\circ f$ on at least one element, so $h_1\circ f\neq h_2\circ f$

**N.B.** Functions with this right cancelation property are called "epic."  There is also a left cancelation property, and functions that satisfy left cancelation are called "monic".  The proof shows that all surjective functions are epic, and one can show that all injective functions are monic.  One reason we care is that we can talk about "epic" or "monic" things even in contexts where injectivity or surjectivity don't quite make sense.

**Proposition:**  If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are epic maps, then $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}\Leftrightarrow g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$

*Proof:* If $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}$, then $g\circ (f\circ g) = g\circ \operatorname{id}=g=\operatorname{id}\circ g.$  However, since $g$ is epic, we can cancel the $g$ on the right: $g\circ f \circ g = \operatorname{id}\circ g$ implies $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$.  The other direction is exactly the same argument.